# Why are websockets an overkill for simpler application?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

From: https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/12/18/websockets-for-fun-and-profit/

> A WebSocket connection is meant to be persisted, so can be overkill for simpler apps.

So when we talk about `socket.io` which is a wrapper around websockets, we won't have to do heavy work to set up the websocket. So, why is it said that persistent connection can be an overkill for simpler apps?

Answer (score 2):

If you read on, it gives an example:

> A WebSocket connection is meant to be persisted, so can be overkill for simpler apps. **For a one-directional news feed, metrics feed, or any app where you need to update the client but not receive information in return, Server Sent Events or plain old HTTP calls are quicker and simpler to set up.**

Websockets are for when you need the server to be able to send data to the client without the client having to initiate the connection themselves first. In the examples quoted, the client can make the request *just once*, when the page first loads, or the server can send the data in the initial document.

socket.io can make working with sockets easier, but it still requires setting some stuff up both on the client-side and the server-side; unless you actually *require* a persistent connection from the server to the client, the setup and the continually open connection won't be accomplishing anything useful.

Comment: `but it still requires setting some stuff up both on the client-side and the server-side;` Please give an example of this in your answer.

Comment: Eg, with Node, you'd need to set up something like https://flaviocopes.com/node-websockets/#implement-a-websockets-server-in-node-js, in addition to opening the connection on the client-side. It's not that you *couldn't* do such a thing, it's just not the appropriate sort of technology for certain tasks.